# Is Math.floor acting like Math.round in ActionScript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, math, actionscript

Here is the problem:

```
var p:int = 0;
var n:Number = 0;
n = 32.999999999999999;
p = Math.floor(n);
trace(p); // returns 33 
n = 32.11111111111111;
p = Math.floor(n);
trace(p); // returns 32
```

I would expect both of these to return 32. I have searched, and it seems this is an unreported bug in AS3. Or ... am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you tried it with just 32.9? It may be that you're trying to be too precise and as such it could be saying that 32.999999999999999 == 33 (ie. since .9 repeating == 1) Did you try just tracing n?

Comment: javascript returns the same result, leading me to believe it's the intended outcome, though it doesn't make sense with the definition of what Floor should do... weird?

Comment: javascript version: http://jsfiddle.net/jpsJ8/

Comment: yeah, seems like it's a known issue with as3 vs as2 as well - this KB article they point to isn't found anymore, but apparently it describes the prob - http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=247416

Comment: Thank you all -- I can't make n 32.9 because it's coming from an audio file, and that's the way ActionScript gets the position in an audio file. Bummer! My real n is often like this:   13202.990233456

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, this is not a bug !!!

You are using number type `double` - [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)][1]. This means you do not have exact numbers, but approximated numbers near the exact value.

For example, if you want to add or subtract smallest possible value to the double value mantissa around number 33, then you get values:

```
32.999999999999986
32.99999999999999
33.0
33.00000000000001
33.000000000000014
```

Thy are essentially closest values around 33 that double value can have. If you did not spot the difference, then

```
32.99999999999999     // closest lower
32.999999999999999    // input value
33.0                  // closest higher
```

Now `32.999999999999999` becomes `33.0` when code is interpreted or parsed as a number. In the same way if you print out `32.9999999999999879` you get `32.999999999999986` - double just does not have bits to store that extra precision, and it will be replaced with closest value. Note again, this is not arithmetically closest, but as it is defined in standard.

Suggested reading: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon

Answer (score 1):

You've just encountered the phenomenon that plagues *all* languages to some degree or another.  Floating Point numbers are really hard to represent in binary, and as such you can lose precision when you use them.

```
var p:int = 0;
var n:Number = 0;
n = 32.999999999999999;
p = Math.floor(n);
trace(p); // returns 33
```

The underlying computer is reading n as being equal to 33 in this case long before you try to call Math.floor.

For more information, see [This wikipedia article about Floating Point, in the section about accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, it's not a bug. If you have `n = 32.999999999999996` it will round down to 32. If you have `n = 32.999999999999997` then it's the same as `n = 33`, so it can't actually round down.